# How do I describe 'stickiness'?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Let's say I spill some coffee or soda on my laptop, and that makes is very sticky and impossible to work with,

So my friend asks me

> What is wrong with your laptop, why is it so sticky?

So what should I say about the coffee or soda?

> There is coffee **sticking on my** keyboard or screen.

Is the last phrase natural or idiomatic? If not, can anyone suggest me a corrected version?

Comment: You can always make something up, eg: YOU: "Oh, that's just F-L-A." FRIEND: "Whats F-L-A?" YOU: "Foreign liquid adhesion." The stickiness comes from sugar, milk, or whipped cream, not coffee.

Comment: I think this is Too Localised. Why on earth would *anyone* need to know the "idiomatic" version of *"There is coffee **stickiness** on my keyboard"*? Are we supposed to have a special version of that for people who don't take sugar, and therefore have *"not-stickiness"* on their keyboard after a spillage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would respond by describing the action that resulted in the current state:

> - I spilled some soda on it earlier.
> - I got some coffee in my keyboard earlier.

Spoken, this would probably have some expression of exasperation or frustration which I wouldn't normally put in writing:

> - Ugh...  I got some coffee on it earlier.
> - *sigh* I spilled something I was drinking on my computer earlier.
> - Agh, I spilled something on it.

I can't think of a natural response that uses your particular word.  However, I can contrive the following sentences to illustrate *stuck to* and *sticky*:

> - There's some dried coffee **stuck to** my screen.
> - There's some dried soda making it **sticky**.

Comment: Oh, you ninja! xP

Answer (score 1):

You could just call it a ***residue***:

> Why is your keyboard so sticky?
>   *That's just a **residue** from when I spilled coffee*.

That's the word used at [this website's](http://www.ehow.com/how_6767333_clean-soda-laptop-keyboard.html#ixzz2ULVEcr4X) column entitled *How to Clean Soda From a Laptop Keyboard*:

> Dampen a cotton swab with water and dab the spilled liquid to dilute the sugar and loosen any caking that has occurred. Use a clean cotton swap to pick up the dried soda **residue** from the keyboard.

A Stack Exchange user also used that word in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/226683/clean-soda-out-of-a-keyboard):

> I spilled Dr Pepper in my Das Keyboard. They are emphatic about not trying to remove the keys lest you break the mechanism. Any ideas on a way to clean out the sticky **residue**?